# How to find the number of losses in a series

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, frequency, loss

I have an array like `[0, 0, 0, 1, 2, -1, -2, 5, 8, 4, 5.5]` and want to find the number of times an element is less than the previous one (ignoring the zeros at the beginning that represent missing data).

In this example, the answer is 3 (for -1, -2 and 4) and I have to divide it by the number of valid numbers (e.g. 8). Expected result is 3/8 = 0.375.

I wrote an instruction and wonder if there is a more efficient way to have it as I have to run it millions of times.

My current instruction:

```
v = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 2, -1, -2, 5, 8, 4, 5.5])
print(np.sum((v < np.roll(v,1))[1:]) / np.sum(v != 0)) # loss frequency
```

Any clue?

Note: as soon as there is a first valid numbers (i.e. different from 0), all following numbers (including 0) are valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [`np.trim_zeros`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.trim_zeros.html) (to trim leading zeros) and simple subtraction:

```
v_trimmed = np.trim_zeros(v, 'f')
np.sum((v_trimmed[1:] - v_trimmed[:-1]) < 0) / len(v_trimmed)
```

Or with `np.diff` for subtraction:

```
np.sum(np.diff(v_trimmed) < 0) / len(v_trimmed)
```

---

```
0.375
```

Comment: The first solution is the fatest one for 5 millions iterations : 28 sec, the second one is 35. Then ouroboros1's first one is 43, his second is 46 and mine is 65 sec. All are giving the same result, which is cool! Thank you RomanPerekhrest

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach:

- Use [`np.argmax`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) to get the index of the first non-zero value (`v != 0`) and slice from there.
- Apply [`np.diff`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html), check for values less than 0 (`< 0`), and apply [`np.sum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) to sum the `True` (1) values.
- Finally divide the sum by the length of the slice.

```
import numpy as np

v = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 2, -1, -2, 5, 8, 4, 5.5])

v_slice = v[np.argmax(v != 0):]

result = np.sum(np.diff(v_slice) < 0) / len(v_slice)

result
# 0.375
```

Or, fully with `np` functions:

```
v_slice = v[np.argmax(v.not_equal(0)):]

result = np.divide(np.sum(np.less(np.diff(v_slice), 0)), v_slice.shape[0])
```

Comment: Thank you ouroboros1 for your solution, it works but the other one is faster.